# Android Runtime NoSuchMethodError

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, android-proguard, android-multidex, android-guava

I recently started getting this error in certain scenarios at run time in my app...

I have already tried the following :

1. Add proguard rules to include `com.google.common`.
2. Mutlidex rules so that all the classes get packaged in main dex file
3. I have checked the apk contents to make sure the classes are present in the dex file...
4. Updgraded my guava android lib to latest 27.0.0-android
5. Updated gradle plugin and gradle version to the latest

> AndroidRuntime: java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: No static method
>   checkArgument(ZLjava/lang/String;I)V in class
>   Lcom/google/common/base/Preconditions;  or its super classes
>   (declaration of 'com.google.common.base.Preconditions' appears in 
>   /data/app/com.myapp.dev.test-Xip2SNDMljPc2_BN0p3iRg==/base.apk!classes2.dex)
>   03-26 13:49:19.167 14658 14751 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.checkPermits(RateLimiter.java:424)
>   03-26 13:49:19.167 14658 14751 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.tryAcquire(RateLimiter.java:341)
>   03-26 13:49:19.167 14658 14751 E AndroidRuntime:  at
>   com.google.common.util.concurrent.RateLimiter.tryAcquire(RateLimiter.java:325)

Not sure where to go from here now. Any ideas what else can I do ?

Comment: how is your proguard configuration file like?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add below proguard configuration

```
-keep class com.google.common.base.**
```

Comment: did not work :( .. I see that both the base and util classes are in main dex file ... even then